# Domain authentication failed for "domain\user"

Tags: c#, active-directory

I used the following code to perform authentication to AD server

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
     return context.ValidateCredentials(samAccountName, password.RetrieveString()
                                               , ContextOptions.Negotiate);
}
```

The thing is, it will only work if I use `"user@domain.com"`, it will not work if I use `"domain\user"`.

Any idea why?

Comment: Did you try passing in the string as `"domain\\user"`?  Have to escape strings properly...

Comment: Hi Merlyn, I use @"domain\user", it is the same, right?

Comment: Yes, that's properly escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Kerberos to work, you need to do 'user@domain' if the user is not currently logged into that domain. If logged into the domain, "domain\user" should work.

This is my experience on our Kerberos network.